# cant echo or touch into file.txt Read only File system

Tags: filesystems, readonly, chrome-os

Hi I cannot touch or Echo into file because it says Read only file system (these are the permissions from the Root directories) how to change file system so I can write files and so forth?

[image: Hi I cannot touch or Echo into file because it says Read only file system (these are the permissions from the Root directories how to change file system so I can write files and so forth?]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Do you have ability to write in your own home-directory? I'm not aware of how Chrome OS (?)  manages its filesystem, but I would not be _surprised_ if the `/` directory was mounted read-only on purpose.

Comment: The message "_Read only file system_" tells you that the filesystem itself is read-only. It doesn't matter what the file permissions are - the file system itself will not permit any writes

Comment: so how do you make it so you can write files? and whats the difference between linux perminting to write files vs a file system permiting to write files?

Comment: When you mount a filesystem it can be mounted read only or read and write. Obviously you want the latter so check how it is being mounted. Filesystems can revert to read only, typically when there are errors or if the hardware is failing. On Linux you would run fsck to fix filesystem error but I’m not sure if that is available on chrome-os.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it manually without Fsck?

Comment: I’ve looked closer at your image and read up a bit on chrome-os. If this were Linux the commands you have used wouldn’t work because you are trying to write to a location where you don’t have write permissions. On Linux the command would work if you preceded it with sudo and have an administrator password when prompted. Chrome-os however expects all user data to be written to the cloud. The only local data is the OS itself so it’s quite likely that it’s read only by design

Comment: theres no way to reformat the drive to make it also read and write?

Comment: I don’t know enough about chrome os to answer that. Why not just use the cloud storage? It may be mounted below /home (but that’s just a guess)

Comment: I want to download some binaries manually to the Bin folder and execute them mainly python

Comment: Looks like you may be able to do this. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911317/how-to-access-the-file-system-in-chrome-os